# Implementing "all except" permissions in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity Enterprise 7.1.3 we currently have the following build chains set up for most of our applications

Build artifacts > deploy to dev > dev acceptance tests > deploy to integration > integration acceptance tests

Developers were all set up as System administrators as we own the dev and integration environments. However, we now want to add a "deploy to test" project and restrict permissions to a few people.

I have set up roles that have permissions explicitly set on all projects except "deploy to test". This works, but with ninety (and growing) projects it is not very maintainable. Every time a new project is created permissions need to be added to these roles.

So my question is: Is there a way in TeamCity to set a role as  except "deploy to test", so that when new projects are added the role automatically has permissions? If not is there best practice for managing this, or do I just need to keep amending permissions as projects are added?

Answer (score 0):

In TeamCity 7.1.3 you are unable to achieve what you are asking. The only way you can do this is to add permissions whenever projects are added. However, if you update to TeamCity 8.x there is now the concept of project hierarchies. You can grant permissions at any level and the permissions are inherited to the sub projects. For example:

- Project A

  - Sub project 1
  - Sub project 2
- Project B

If you give a developer permissions to project A and then add a new sub project:

- Project A

  - Sub project 1
  - Sub project 2
  - Sub project 3
- Project B

There will have permission to all 3 sub-projects in project A without having to change the permissions model. This should achieve exactly what you are after.